# How to parse nslookup result by regex

Tags: php, regex

I have 2 different nslookup results:

```
Server:  PROXY.LOCAL
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2a02:598:2::1168
     77.75.77.168
```

and

```
Server:  router.local
Address:  192.168.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 3 seconds.
Name:    google.com
Address:  216.58.207.46
```

My regex code looks like this:

```
$re = '~(?:Name:\s*\S+\s*)\K(?:\G(?!\A)|^Addresses:|^Address:)\s*\K\S\S\S+~m';
```

Problem is that when `Addresses:` exists it will return only first IP, not second one on new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your approach is that you "anchored" the match at the `(?:Name:\s*\S+\s*)\K` pattern. The `\K` operator does not make the preceding pattern non-consuming, and that text must appear for a match to occur.

You should make sure the pattern adheres to a scheme like:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|<START_PATTERN>)<PATTERN_TO_CONSUME_AND_OMIT>\K<PATTERN_TO_EXTRACT>
```

That is, your current pattern follows the [`abc\s+(?:\G(?!\A)|d)\s*\K\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/9WUkGe/1) scheme, and it should be [`(?:\G(?!\A)|abc\s+d)\s*\K\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/9WUkGe/2).

You may fix it using

```
'~(?:\G(?!\A)\R\h+|^Name:\s*\S+\s*Address(?:es)?:)\s*\K\S+~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vghUJF/1).

It matches

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\R\h+|^Name:\s*\S+\s*Address(?:es)?:)` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`) + a line break and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars (`\h+`) or (`|`) a sequence of the following patterns:

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `Name:` -  a literal substring
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `Address` - a literal substring
  - `(?:es)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching `es` substring 1 or 0 times
  - `:`  -  a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` -  match reset operator (discarding all the text matched so far)
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Note I added `\h+` after `\G(?!\A)` to make sure the next line starts with 1+ horizontal whitespaces, in order to stop matching if the next line starts with a non-whitespace char.